# Get evenly spaced X, Y cords from a given size and required amount

Tags: arrays, actionscript

I'm working in Actionscript 3, but this is pretty general.

I'd like to make a simple function that I can call, e.g. GiveCords(Width, Height, Num) that will take a width and height, map that out and using the Num variable place the given amount evenly across the space.

Say I give it a value of 500, 500, 1. I'd expect it to return an X, Y position of 250, 250.

But I'd like it to return an array of given points with X, Y.

So If I gave it 10 points, it would find the best position for them all to be of even distance apart from each other.

I'm guessing there is a simple formula for working this out, but I've searched a plenty and found nothing.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly this should do the job:

```
var object:Object = {width: 500, height:500, num:10};
var points:Array = getCoordinates(object);

function getCoordinates(object:Object):Array {

   var array:Array = new Array();
   var widthMultiplier:Number = object.width / (object.num + 1);
   var heightMultiplier:Number = object.height / (object.num + 1);

   for (a = 1; a <= object.num; a++) {
      var coordinates:Point = new Point();
      coordinates.x = widthMultiplier * a;
      coordinates.y = heightMultipler * a;
      array.push(coordinates);
   }

return array;
}
```

It takes the number of items and the total space, divides the total space by the number of items + 1 (to account for the space at the end of the last element) increment the objects each time.

Edit: In response to comments here is a version where you can state the number of rows you want your objects to spread across. If the number of rows does not divide the number of objects and return an integer then the function will return null. If you do not give it a rows paramater it assumes you want it across one row. Enjoy.

```
var object:Object = {width:500,height:500,num:10};
var points:Array = getCoordinates(object,2);

function getCoordinates(object:Object, rows:int = 1):Array
{
    if ((object.num / rows) % 1)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        var columns:int = object.num / rows;

        var array:Array = new Array();
        var widthMultiplier:Number = object.width / (columns + 1);
        var heightMultiplier:Number = object.height / (rows + 1);

        for (var a = 1; a <= rows; a++)
        {
            for (var b = 1; b <= columns; b++)
            {
                var coordinates:Point = new Point();
                coordinates.x = widthMultiplier * b;
                coordinates.y = heightMultiplier * a;
                array.push(coordinates);
            }
        }

        return array;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is halfway there! The only problem with this is that it only gives diagonal values, I'd like them to be evenly spaced throughout the given width/height, e.g. left/right/up/down, not just top left to bottom right.

Comment: @JohnRake This isn't possible without telling it how many you want per row or column, seeing how there are multiple combinations... for 10 it has to ether be 5 x 2 or 2 x 5 it is only square numbers that have obvious answers e.g. 16 would be 4 x 4. You need to give it preference over whether you want more objects in a row or a column then I can do this.

Comment: I can certainly tell it how many per row/column as an extra value - that'd be great!

Comment: @JohnRake Answer updated with a version that let's you tell it how many rows you want.